# How to check if a password reset token is still valid?

Tags: 8, users

Is there a way to hook into the `user_pass_reset` form to detect if the provided hash is valid? Currently it seems to just throw a 403 error when submitting the form if the hash has already been used to change the password.

Using `hook_form_alter()`, I can retrieve the hash itself with `explode("/",$form['#action'])[5]`, but am unsure how to check if it's already been used or not, or if it's expired. I see that this information might be part of the `UserController` class, but I'm not sure how to retrieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I probably should have gotten the idea to follow where the form action actually takes you and see what its controller does. I pulled the timestamp and hash from the form action with the explode function, loaded the user object from the currentUser id, and used `Crypt::hashEquals($hash, user_pass_rehash($user, $timestamp));`.